# Disable inputs dynamically on selects change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this initial html code it creates a select and input and a button:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control name_list" name="product[]" id="prod_1" required="required">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
                            <option value="on">ON</option>
                            <option value="off">OFF</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qte[]" id="qte_1" placeholder="Qte" class="form-control name_list" required="required"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <a name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and I have some jQuery code that allows me to add as much as I want of the same selects and inputs:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var i = 1;
            $('#add').click(function () {
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_field').append(
                    '<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<select class="form-control name_list" name="product[]" id="prod_' + i + '" required="required">' +
                    '<option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>' +
                    '<option value="on">ON</option>' +
                    '<option value="off">OFF</option>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="number" name="qte[]" id="qte_' + i + '" placeholder="Qte" class="form-control name_list" required="required"/></td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<a type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</a>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '</tr>'
                    );
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

What I want is whenever I change the status of the select to "OFF", the associated input gets disable dynamically.

for example for the first one:

```
$(document).on('change', '#prod_1', function () {
                var x = $('#prod_1').val();
                if (x == "off") {
                    $('#qte_1').prop('disabled', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#qte_1').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
```

Comment: If you have multiple rows, be sure to fix that `id="add"` on the button in the rows. You can't have more than one `id="add"` in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `classname` on change function instead of `id` .unique id creation is not a good idea .

1. [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwje_4WN2dHVAhUEto8KHbj-AnsQFgi_ATAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AFQjCNGkhpVv76EWvWWYjEID4qvdUghHMQ) used find the closest selector from parent element
2. [`find()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi59qWr2dHVAhXIQY8KHSKQDTwQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffind%2F&usg=AFQjCNG-8t8FlAFURjmRfahbB_JtshKgfg) used for select the innerElement

```js
$(document).on('change', '.name_list', function() {
  var x = $(this).val();
  if (x == "off") {
    $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append(
      '<tr id="row' + i + '" class="row">' +
      '<td>' +
      '<select class="form-control name_list" name="product[]" id="prod_' + i + '" required="required">' +
      '<option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>' +
      '<option value="on">ON</option>' +
      '<option value="off">OFF</option>' +
      '</select>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="number" name="qte[]" id="qte_' + i + '" placeholder="Qte" class="form-control name_list" required="required"/></td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<a type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</a>' +
      '</td>' +
      '</tr>'
    );
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control name_list" name="product[]" id="prod_1" required="required">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
                            <option value="on">ON</option>
                            <option value="off">OFF</option>
                        </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="qte[]" id="qte_1" placeholder="Qte" class="form-control name_list" required="required" /></td>
        <td>
          <a name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch any number from the ID using a regex, and use that number to select the checkbox

```
$(document).on('change', '[id^=prod_]', function () {
    var v = this.value;
    var n = this.id.replace(/\D+/,'')

    $('#qte_' + n).prop('disabled', v === 'off');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append(
      '<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
      '<td>' +
      '<select class="form-control name_list" name="product[]" id="prod_' + i + '" required="required">' +
      '<option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>' +
      '<option value="on">ON</option>' +
      '<option value="off">OFF</option>' +
      '</select>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="number" name="qte[]" id="qte_' + i + '" placeholder="Qte" class="form-control name_list" required="required"/></td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<a type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</a>' +
      '</td>' +
      '</tr>'
    );
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });

  $(document).on('change', '[id^=prod_]', function() {
    var v = this.value;
    var n = this.id.replace(/\D+/, '')
    $('#qte_' + n).prop('disabled', v === 'off');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control name_list" name="product[]" id="prod_1" required="required">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
            <option value="on">ON</option>
            <option value="off">OFF</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="qte[]" id="qte_1" placeholder="Qte" class="form-control name_list" required="required" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <a name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i didnt really understand ur code but i try it and there is a syntax error here `var n = this.id.replace(\D,'');`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `id`s for this at all, just handle `change` on all `name='product[]'` selects and then find the `input[name='qte[]']` in the same row:

```
$(document).on("change", "select[name='product[]']", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='qte[]']").prop("disabled", $this.val() == "off");
});
```

*(If there's only ever one input in the row, you could leave the `[name='qte[]']` part off if you want.)*

**Live Example:**

```js
$(document).on("change", "select[name='product[]']", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest("tr").find("input[name='qte[]']").prop("disabled", $this.val() == "off");
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control name_list" name="product[]" required="required">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
                            <option value="on">ON</option>
                            <option value="off">OFF</option>
                        </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="qte[]" placeholder="Qte" class="form-control name_list" required="required" /></td>
        <td>
          <a name="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control name_list" name="product[]" required="required">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
                            <option value="on">ON</option>
                            <option value="off">OFF</option>
                        </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="qte[]" placeholder="Qte" class="form-control name_list" required="required" /></td>
        <td>
          <a name="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control name_list" name="product[]" required="required">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
                            <option value="on">ON</option>
                            <option value="off">OFF</option>
                        </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="qte[]" placeholder="Qte" class="form-control name_list" required="required" /></td>
        <td>
          <a name="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*(I've removed the `id`s in that example, but you can leave them if you use them for something else — except for the `id="add"` on the buttons, which you'll need to make unique.)*